# How to grab other local tag data in Swift?

Tags: swift, variables, tags, local

I am working on saving data process,
because my data is small, so I want to save in local data storage.
I want a make time schedule.

Because I have single 35 buttons and label(each buttons and label are paired), So I am using UIButton tag now. And I have a problem on using other local data "tag".

I tired to make new func on global swift file(same swift file). but it is not able to call tag, because tag is only can use when UIbutton pressed.
I want to use tag property on viewDidLoad(), not only in UIbuttonPressed.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        if let items = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "SubjectList") as? [String] {
            subjectArray = items
            UITextLabel**1**.text = subjectArray**[1-1]**
            }
        } 

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        var textField = UITextField() 
        let newItem = textField.text!        
        if sender.tag == 1{
            self.subjectArray[sender.tag-1] = newItem
            print("1")
        }
UserDefaults.standard.set(self.subjectArray, forKey: "SubjectList") 
        }
```

Comment: I want to grab tag data in viewDidLoad()

Answer (score 2):

Create outlet collections for all the paired labels and buttons

```
@IBOutlet weak var allLbls:[UILabel]!
@IBOutlet weak var allBts:[UIButton]!
```

---

In `viewDidLoad`

```
if let items = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "SubjectList") as? [String] {
   subjectArray = items 
   subjectArray.indices?.forEach { 
       allLbls[$0].text = subjectArray[$0]
       allBts[$0].tag = $0
   }
}
```

Comment: I have a question for [$0].
What I want to do is, like making time schedule.
When I pressed button, and edit, that can change label state on button.
Is $0 can make it matching together?

Comment: Oh you means I only need to add this on my project right?